# Formatting a date like 2013-11-01T08:50:43.305Z

Tags: php, date

Maybe a trivial question but I can't seem to figure this out. I need to format a date like `2013-11-01T08:50:43.305Z` in PHP. I'm not sure how to add `.305Z`-part in the formatting. I've been looking at the docs (php's date-function documentation) but I must have overread it there... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just concatenate ? `$date = $date.'.305Z';`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I think these are milliseconds which are for every timestamp different. Your solution is a bit to pragmatic ;-).

Comment: Because I don't know what it stands for. And now @TiMESPLiNTER explained ;) thanks.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER this is not a timestamp this is number of day of that year.

Comment: Actually I do believe it is the number of milli seconds, I also saw values over 365, like 705, 889 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
echo date("c");
```

For more reference see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Or you can use this format:

```
echo date("Y-m-dh:i:sz");
```

Here **Z** means the number of day in the current year.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing it myself too. I'm trying to connect with an API but the .305Z-part wasn't necessary to add in the headers. This works.